# I need one string with max value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max, limit

I have such quire:

```
SELECT s_name, count(Mark)
FROM specialty
join interns_specialty on specialty.specialty_id = interns_specialty.specialty_id
join practice_result on practice_result.Intern_id = interns_specialty.intern_id
where Mark=5
group by specialty.specialty_id
ORDER by count(Mark) DESC;
```

[That is what i get from my quire, i need to take the row with the max count of excellent marks, if there is two or more such rows, i must to get it all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJhGz.png)
I need to get one string with the name of specialty which has more excellent marks than others.
But i can`t understand how to do this. I tried to use "Limit", but if i have two or more specialties - it will be work incorrect. I couldn`t use MAX with another aggregate functions, so i need an advice.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: If different `s_name` (from what table it is taken?) values may match the same `specialty.specialty_id` then your query makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina I don`t understand, you said that this query makes no sense, but it works. It give me specialty with its marks. So i need only to chose the specialty or specialties with more quantity of 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @jarlh And what does it mean? And what i need to do?

Comment: Does the condition "more than one `s_name` matches the same `specialty.specialty_id`" is true? if so - you obtain only one value from all possible ones... and what's the sense?

Comment: @Akina I understand what are you talking about, but i dont understand why i have the normal result?

Comment: *i dont understand why i have the .. result?* Because `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is disabled. *i dont understand why i have the normal result?* This is random - at any time it may give another `s_name` whereas neither query nor source data were changed.

Comment: @Akina What if i will replace "s_name" on specialty.specialty_id?

Comment: Your query become correct.

Comment: @Akina TY. But it does not solve my problem. What do you think about my question? What i need to use?

Comment: RANK() as Gordon claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `rank()`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT s.s_name, COUNT(*),
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM specialty s JOIN
           interns_specialty ins
           ON s.specialty_id = ins.specialty_id JOIN
           practice_result pr
           ON pr.Intern_id = ins.intern_id
      WHERE Mark = 5
      GROUP BY s.specialty_id
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: but what if it will be two strings with same quantity of excellent marks?

Comment: @AntonTuhusov All of them will be returned (maybe it's more simple to test?).

Comment: @Akina ,спасибо, но я не могу протестить ))

Comment: @AntonTuhusov Why? test on any online fiddle... PS. Do not use national language there.